# Datetime Daylight savings transition problem [Python]

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I get the following error for my timestamp field when converting from UTC to CET due to the transition to daylight savings last Saturday/Sunday:

```
AmbiguousTimeError: Cannot infer dst time from 2020-07-31 11:17:18+00:00, try using the 'ambiguous' argument
```

#converting timestamp fields to CET (Europe,Berlin)

```
df['timestamp_berlin_time'] = df['timestamp'].dt.tz_localize('Europe/Berlin')
```

I tried the following snippet:

```
df['timestamp_berlin_time'] = df['timestamp'].dt.tz_localize('CET',ambiguous='infer')
```

but this gives me then this error:

```
AmbiguousTimeError: 2020-07-31 11:17:18+00:00
```

Data sample:

```
0  2020-07-31 11:17:18+00:00
1  2020-07-31 11:17:18+00:00
2  2020-08-31 16:26:42+00:00
3  2020-10-20 07:28:46+00:00
4  2020-10-01 22:11:33+00:00
```

Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]

Comment: can you clarify what is giving you the error? what is the data type of `df['timestamp']`?

Comment: just updated my post: the datatype for both fields is: datetime64[ns, UTC] and the I get the error for both fields when I convert them to CET

Comment: The sample is based on the timestamp  that is causing the error when using: dt.tz_localize to convert from UTC to CET

Comment: to go from UTC to CEST/CET, use `tz_convert`, see my answer, second part.

Comment: this gives me then this error:  Cannot convert tz-naive timestamps, use tz_localize to localize

Comment: ok that is weird... are you sure the whole column is correctly localized to UTC (datetime64[ns, UTC])? otherwise, you could try to localize to UTC first before converting to tz Europe/Berlin.

Comment: this worked! perfect, thanks!

Comment: ok great! I've adjusted the answer to reflect comments ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is UTC but UTC isn't set yet, you can localize to UTC first, here e.g.:

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.tz_localize('UTC')
```

If your input already is converted to UTC, you can simply `tz_convert`, e.g.:

```
s = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(['2020-10-25 00:40:03.925000', 
                              '2020-10-25 01:40:03.925000', 
                              '2020-10-25 02:40:03.925000'], utc=True))

s.dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')
# 0   2020-10-25 02:40:03.925000+02:00
# 1   2020-10-25 02:40:03.925000+01:00
# 2   2020-10-25 03:40:03.925000+01:00
# dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]
```

If your input timestamps represent local time (here: Europe/Berlin time zone), you can try to infer the DST transition based on order:

```
s = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(['2020-10-25 02:40:03.925000', 
                              '2020-10-25 02:40:03.925000', 
                              '2020-10-25 03:40:03.925000']))

s.dt.tz_localize('Europe/Berlin', ambiguous='infer')
# 0   2020-10-25 02:40:03.925000+02:00
# 1   2020-10-25 02:40:03.925000+01:00
# 2   2020-10-25 03:40:03.925000+01:00
# dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]
```

Note: CET is not a time zone in a geographical sense. pytz can handle some of these for historical reasons but don't count on it. In any case, it might give you static tz offsets - which is not what you want if you expect it to include DST transitions.

Comment: I still get this error: AmbiguousTimeError: 2020-10-25 02:40:03.925000 when converting from UTC to CET

Comment: @user12625679: then the inference from the order of the timestamps doesn't work. could you provide a working [mre]?